# Python AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot, proxy, python-3.6

Мой код:

```
import telebot
from telebot import apihelper

token="здесь токен"
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)
apihelper.proxy = {
   'http', "socks5://login:pass@12.11.22.33:8000",
   'https', "socks5://login:pass@12.11.22.33:8000"
 }

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

До добавления proxy бот просто выдавал ошибку авторизации из-за того, что ТГ в РФ заблокирован, поэтому добавил proxy. После добавления ошибку начала вызывать функция `bot.polling(none_stop=True)`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lyonya/telebot/main.py", line 18, in <module>
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
  File "/home/lyonya/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 455, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(none_stop, interval, timeout, long_polling_timeout)
  File "/home/lyonya/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 513, in __threaded_polling
    raise e
  File "/home/lyonya/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 478, in __threaded_polling
    polling_thread.raise_exceptions()
  File "/home/lyonya/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 88, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
  File "/home/lyonya/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 69, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/lyonya/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 295, in __retrieve_updates
    updates = self.get_updates(offset=(self.last_update_id + 1), timeout=timeout, long_polling_timeout = long_polling_timeout)
  File "/home/lyonya/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 265, in get_updates
    json_updates = apihelper.get_updates(self.token, offset, limit, timeout, allowed_updates, long_polling_timeout)
  File "/home/lyonya/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telebot/apihelper.py", line 248, in get_updates
    return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload)
  File "/home/lyonya/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telebot/apihelper.py", line 109, in _make_request
    timeout=(connect_timeout, read_timeout), proxies=proxy)
  File "/home/lyonya/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 521, in request
    prep.url, proxies, stream, verify, cert
  File "/home/lyonya/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 698, in merge_environment_settings
    no_proxy = proxies.get('no_proxy') if proxies is not None else None
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: попробуйте изменить socks5 на socks5h?

Comment: @Jack_oS requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: SOCKSHTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot1508766650:AAFUQzRRj5q6-W5J2wtvj2QdZi3LhYoBS4Y/getUpdates?offset=1&timeout=20 (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.contrib.socks.SOCKSHTTPSConnection object at 0xb644458c>, 'Connection to api.telegram.org timed out. (connect timeout=3.5)'))

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы создать словарь надо писать так:

```
{a: b}
```

а вы создаёте множество

```
{a, b}
```

поэтому надо писать так:

```
{
   'http': "socks5://login:pass@12.11.22.33:8000",
   'https': "socks5://login:pass@12.11.22.33:8000"
 }
```

Comment: Действительно, я допустил ошибку в этом, спасибо! НО! Как только я это исправил - вернулась ошибка с telegram и proxy: https://pastebin.com/4nzAt0c2 и показывает он все на ту же строчку (если ее убрать, то программа заканчивается без ошибок)

Comment: Добавил вместо нее bot.infinity_polling - тогда программа запускается и работает, но бот не отвечает на команды

Comment: @Nezerix извините, но я не разбираюсь в ботах